# create Expression tree in c# to select multiple records using LINQ.Expressions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

For the following sample student list I want to select multiple records from the list using Expression tree(to generate dynamic LINQ query)

```
 - 1 | John  | 13
 - 2 | Steve | 15
 - 3 | Bill  | 18
 - 4 | Ram   | 12
 - 5 | Ron   | 21
```

**For selecting single record**

```
SQL Query:   
select * from studentList where StudentID = 2
```

LINQ:

```
var studentsData = studentList.Where(s=>s.StudentID == 2).AsQueryable();
```

likewise I need to create Expression tree for selecting multiple records from the list of values

**For example SQL Query:**

```
From the list of IDs I need create expression for selecting records     
select * from studentList where StudentID in (2,4,3)
```

*sample Output:*

```
 - 2 | Steve
 - 4 | Ram
 - 3 | Bill
```

**Sample Expression tree Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
        new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 13 } ,
        new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 15 } ,
        new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 18 } ,
        new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 12 } ,
        new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 21 } 
    };
    var studentwithLinQ = studentList.Where(s=>s.StudentID == 2);
    foreach(var stu in studentwithLinQ)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}",stu.StudentID, stu.StudentName);
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student), "s");
    MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, "StudentID");
    int id = 2;
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(id, typeof(int));
    BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(me, constant);
    Expression predicateExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, pe);
    var sourcequery = studentList.AsQueryable();
    Expression sourceExpression = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(sourcequery), typeof(IQueryable<Student>));
    Expression filterExpressionExpression = Expression.Constant(predicateExpression);
    var queryExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new Type[] { typeof(Student)}, sourceExpression,filterExpressionExpression);
    sourcequery = Expression.Lambda(queryExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke() as IQueryable<Student>;
    Console.WriteLine("sourceExpression: {0}", sourcequery);
    var studentWithExpression = sourcequery;
    foreach(var stu in studentWithExpression)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}",stu.StudentID, stu.StudentName);
   }
 }

public class Student{
   public int StudentID { get; set; }
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I can create a Expression code for selecting single record. But i am not able to select the values using multiple records from datalist.can you please help me to select multiple values using Expression Statments.

Answer (score 2):

I think trying to get it fixed with expressions it a hell of a job. These functionality can already be achieved with existing methods. *(which keeps your solution much more simplistic)* ;-)

You could try this:

```
// your original set
IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 13 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 15 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 18 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 12 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 21 } 
};

// create a subselection of ids only into an array(or list) of the id's only.
// results in `int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`
var ids = studentList.Select(student => student.StudentID).ToArray();

// use it on the studentList.
var studentwithLinQ = studentList.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.StudentID));
```

**The ids array will be converted to an `IN (..)` statement.**

Answer (score 1):

You *can* create an expression tree for this, but that is doing things the hard way. Much simpler is to just create a list of the ids:

```
var ids = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };
```

and just use:

```
var filtered = studentList.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.StudentID));
```